# Short form of same author

Tags: biblatex

I'm having a problem while writing my project paper. I'm quoting the United Nations multiple times so doing that I have to use the short form of the author. As a result my paper should look like this:

```
Vgl. UN-Sicherheitsrat: S/RES/660 (1990), 02.09.1990. <http://www.un.org/Depts/german/sr/sr_90/sr660-90.pdf> (abgerufen 27.09.2014).

Vgl. UN-SR: S/RES/661 (1990), 06.09.1990. <http://www.un.org/Depts/german/sr/sr_90/sr661-90.pdf> (abgerufen 27.09.2014).
```

Samples:

bibliography:

```
@MISC{UN:660,
  AUTHOR       = "UN-Sicherheitsrat",
  TITLE        = "S/RES/660 (1990), 02.09.1990",
  NOTE         = "\textless\url{http://www.un.org/Depts/german/sr/sr_90/sr660-90.pdf}\textgreater \addspace (abgerufen 27.09.2014"
}

@MISC{UN:661,
  AUTHOR       = "UN-Sicherheitsrat",
  TITLE        = "S/RES/661 (1990), 06.09.1990",
  NOTE         = "\textless\url{http://www.un.org/Depts/german/sr/sr\_90/sr661-90.pdf}\textgreater\addspace (abgerufen 27.09.2014)"
}
```

Main Tex-file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\bibliography{literature}

\begin{document}
Text-sample1\autocite[Vgl.][]{UN:660}
Text-sample2\autocite[Vgl.][]{UN:661}
\end{document}
```

Is there any possibility to create my own short names for organizations?

The deadline is next Tuesday and I can't find a solution, so I'm a bit desperate at the moment.

Hoping for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a second solution not depending on the dynamic manipulation of the data in the bibtex records, and does not require to know which is the first citation for a given name.

The solution makes use of the field `shortauthor`, in case the field is not present in the original bibtex records one can add dynamically as follows:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=author, match={UN-Sicherheitsrat}, fieldset=shortauthor, fieldvalue={UN-SR}]
    }
  }
}
```

The idea is create a list of the author names used in a document. To this end one can use the `fullhash` field.  According to the `biblatex` manual  (`texdoc biblatex`)

> `fullhash` A hash string which uniquely identifies the `labelname`list. This fields differs from `name hash` in two details: 1) The `shortauthor` and `short editor` lists are ignored when generating the hash. 2) The hash always refers to the full list, ignoring `maxnames` and `minnames`. See also `hash` and `namehash`.

We have to create a list that contains such hash values.

```
\def\citednames{}
```

and a boolean used to determine if a name hash already been used in a citation

```
\newbool{namecited}
```

The next step is to identify if a name has been used, namely if it is in the list. We can do that using the `\AtEveryCitekey` hook which is executed before invoking  the main loop of a cite command (and the values of the bibtex field are available)

```
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \xifinlist{\thefield{fullhash}}{\citednames}
    {\booltrue{namecited}}
    {\listxadd{\citednames}{\thefield{fullhash}}\boolfalse{namecited}}%
}
```

Here, we check if the `fullhash` value is in the list of the already cited names, if it is, we set the boolean `namecited` to true. Otherwise, we insert the `fullhash` in the list and we set `namecited` to false.

The final step is to give the instruction on what name to use (i.e., the full name or  the short name) depending on whether `namecited` is true or false.

To this task we take advantage of the `xpatch` package (i.e., load `\usepackage{xpatch}` in the preamble) and we patch the `author` bibmacro.

```
\xpatchbibmacro{author}
  {\printnames{author}}
  {\ifbool{namecited}{\printnames{labelname}}{\printnames{author}}}
  {}
  {}
```

This solution, given

```
\begin{document}

\listadd{\citednames}{text}
Text-sample1\autocite[Vgl.][]{UN:660}
Text-sample2\autocite[Vgl.][]{UN:661}
Text-sample3\autocite[Vgl.][]{UN:660}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution requiring some manual intervention and `biblatex`  (with `biber` backend) ability to dynamically manipulate bibtex entry field.

This solution requires to know which one is the first entry for a particular name.

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=entrykey, match={UN:660}, fieldset=shortauthor, fieldvalue={UN-SR}]
    }
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=author, match={UN-Sicherheitsrat}, replace={UN-SR}]
      \step[fieldsource=entrykey, match={UN:660}, fieldset=author, fieldvalue={UN-Sicherheitsrat}]
    }
  }
}
```

The first step is to introduce a `shortauthor` value for the first entry (here the entry with key `UN:660`). In this way, the style used in the MWE will use the full name for the first reference and the value of `shortauthor` for the successive citations.

The second step is to  replace all occurrences of `author` (for all the entries with the same value of author as the selected entry, in the example the entry with entrykay `UN:660`) with the value of `shortauthor`. The final step is to restore the original value of `author` for the first occurrence.

For

```
\begin{document}
Text-sample1\autocite[Vgl.][]{UN:660}
Text-sample2\autocite[Vgl.][]{UN:661}
Text-sample3\autocite[Vgl.][]{UN:660}
\end{document}
```

the solution above produces

[image]

Comment: First, I'm glad for the detailed information given. 

But that's not quite what I was searching for. I need to cite the organization's name full the first time (so "United Nations - Security Council" in the english version), but if I quote the same organization a second time, the Abbreviate should be used (so "UN-SC"). 

Is it possible to implement some kind of counting-mechanism to use the techniques you mentioned?

Comment: Given the style you use, `\shorthand` will replace the author for the second citation of the same reference but not for different references (and also it will remove the note, in your case the url).  If you don't have to cite many different organization, and you know what is the first instance to be cited, you can selectively (and manually) use the map above with a step where you add the `shorthand` to the first to be cited.  A full solution is possible but it takes a bit more time to be implemented.

Comment: That was exactly what I was searching for, thank you very much. But now, this Abbreviation is also used in the Bibliography at the end. Can I somehow exclude the bibliography from this rule?

Comment: No, you cannot. See the other solution operates only on citations, so it does not affect the bibliography.